# How do I add a second click event to an a tag that already has an href?

Tags: html, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I need to add a second click event to a link.  I would like to add a modal event like shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO) - but it already uses the HREF for the download link.  What is the best way to handle this?

```
<a download href="/path-to-file"><strong>DOWNLOAD</strong></a>
```

To be clear.  I need the link to file to stay as is but also trigger the popup.

Comment: What is that popup supposed to do?

Comment: Display a message, which isn't relative to the action of it popping up.

Comment: It's [trivial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) with [javascript](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/LYxbmmY).

Comment: @tao I see you tweaked the popup to use JS -- but it's using the href attribute to call the JS code for the popup to appear. But HOW can I get both at the same time?  The 'trivial' link is just modifying the text and color.  I need to maintain the download attribute.

Comment: Nope. `javascript:void(0)` means "do nothing" in plain English. I simply needed a valid `href` on the element, so that it behaved like a normal link (without a `href`, the browser renders it differently). I could have given it `href="#"` but that scrolls to top of page (it wouldn't affect your example, but, if copy pasted in a different context, it might have). See my answer for a quick rundown through your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<a>` element can trigger functionality on its way to its `href` (target). It has a built-in HTML property (global event handler, to be specific), called [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), that's common across most HTML content elements.

The `onclick` handler will be performed first. It takes an attribute (named `event`), which is the [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent).

So this will work:

```html
<script lang="javascript">
  function doSomething(e) {
    console.log(`You clicked <${e.target.localName}>`);

    debugger;
    // Press F8 to resume execution

  }
</script>
<a download href="/path-to-file" onclick="doSomething(event)"><strong>DOWNLOAD</strong></a>
```

The [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) pointer event bubbles. Which means once the `onclick` handler bound on the element has been executed, the document looks for any other `onclick` handlers bound on its ancestors (parent elements). If it finds them, it executes them as well, in order (closest first), all the way up to `document` (which contains `<body>`, as `.body`).

What this means is that you don't necessarily have to bind your `onclick` handler onto the element with the `href` itself. You can bind it on any of its parents and it will still be performed before the document goes to the `<a>`'s `href`:

```html
<script lang="javascript">
  function doSomething(e) {
    console.log(`You clicked <${e.target.localName}>`);
    // uncomment next line to stop it getting to href (and see the log above)
    // e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
<div onclick="doSomething(event)">
  <a download href="/path-to-file"><strong>DOWNLOAD</strong></a>
</div>
```

You can call `.preventDefault()` on the `event` to stop it from going to `href` and from bubbling.
To stop it from bubbling but still allow it to go to its `href` you can call `.stopPropagation()` on it.

---

Note: throughout my answer I used links to the MDN web docs. Instead, I could (some might even say should) have used links to the actual HTML Living Standard (a.k.a. *"official HTML documentation"*). I chose not to, because most people find the Standard too technical, therefore harder to digest. But note every MDN page has a link to the official documentation for that resource at the bottom of the page.